# How to Validate two columns when a column must start with another column?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have two columns namely `C1(abc,def,qwe)` and `C2(abc:ttt,abc:red,def:oiu,qwe:some,qwe:pot)` which are dropdown in a list. When I select abc in C1 and def:oiu in C2, it must throw an error. C2 must take choice that starts with C1 option only.

I Used `list validation` with formula :

> =IF(LEFT([C2],FIND(":",[C2])-1)=[C1],TRUE,FALSE)

But its not validating.

Comment: I tried your formula in my test list and it works just fine. Just to confirm, validation will display error message when you click on save and not when you select value.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct, could be made clearer to read,

```
=LEFT([C2],FIND(":",[C2])-1)=[C1]
```

itself  returns a TRUE/FALSE value

You want C1 to start at position 1 of C2

You could also write

```
=ISLOGICAL( FIND([C1],[C2])=1 )
```

You have dropdown lists, so "ab" matching "abc:" does not occur in your situation

```
=LEFT( [C2] ,  LEN([C1])  ) = [C1]
```

Matches whole of C1